# Counting occurrence in singly linked list by nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I am writing a simple app that gets a `list` and saves the objects as `nodes` in a *singly linked list* and we can `add()`, `remove()`, `copy()`, etc. each node depending on the given data set. each node has a `char value` which is our data and an `int count` which counts the occurrence of the related `char`.

e.g. for a list like

> a, a, b, b, c, a

there would be three nodes (since there are three different characters) which are:

> `[a,3,*next] -> [b,2,*next] -> [c,1,*next] -> nullptr`

`bool isAvailable()` checks if the data is already in the list or not.

Q: When inserting a data there are two options:

1. The data has not been entered: so we have to create a `newNode`with the given data, `count=1`and `*next=NULL`.
2. The data is already entered: so we have to `count++` the node that has the same data.

I know if the given data is available or not, but how can I point to the node with same data?

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Snode
{
public:
    char data;
    int count;
    Snode *next;
    Snode(char d, int c)
    {
        data = d;
        count = c;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class set
{
private:
    Snode *head;
public:
    set()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }
    ~set();
    void insert(char value);
    bool isAvailable(char value);
};

set::~set()
{
    Snode *t = head;
    while (t != NULL)
    {
        head = head->next;
        delete t;
    }
}

bool set::isAvailable(char value)
{
    Snode *floatingNode = new Snode(char d, int c);
    while(floatingNode != NULL)
    {
        return (value == floatingNode);
        floatingNode->next = floatingNode;
    }
}

void set::insert(char value)
{
    Snode *newNode = new Snode(char d, int c);
    data = value;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        head = newNode;
        newNode->count++;
    }
    else
    {
        if(isAvailable)
        {
            //IDK what should i do here +_+
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next= newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `head` and   `tail` ; where are they from? and `head = NULL;  tail = NULL;` how can this be done?

Comment: tail     is a mistake, ignore it. and     head     is the first node in the list which is equal to NULL at first.

Comment: @SaufenmitProgramming

Comment: I'm sorry to have to tell you this, but your code has some very serious bugs. You must work on simpler exercises for a while yet.

Comment: "*When inserting a data there are two options:...*" - it would make more sense to use an in-order insertion so there is some kind of order to the data in your list (and greatly reduce the number of iterations required to find `'A'`, etc..) Further, if you are only dealing with ASCII characters, a fixed integer array of `128` elements with indexes corresponding to the ASCII value of each character make a whole lot more sense. If you are just doing this for a learning exercise, then the linked-list is a fine choice.

Comment: As an aside, naming your data structure `set` and implementing a (singly) linked list will confuse people who know what `std::set` is. For your particular purpose, a `std::map<char, int>` or `std::array<int, 256>` are much more suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know if the given data is available or not, but how can I point to the node with same data?

You'll need to start at the head of the list and iterate along the list by following the `next` pointers until you find the node with the same `data` value.  Once you've done that, you have your pointer to the node with the same data.

Some other notes for you:

```
bool set::isAvailable(char value)
{
   Snode *floatingNode = new Snode(char d, int c);
   while(floatingNode != NULL)
   {
       return (value == floatingNode);
       floatingNode->next = floatingNode;
   }
}
```

1. Why is this function allocating a `new Snode`?  There's no reason for it to do that, just initialize the `floatingNode` pointer to point to `head` instead.
2. This function always returns after looking at only the first node in the linked list -- which is not the behavior you want.  Instead, it should return true only if (value == floatingNode); otherwise it should stay inside the while-loop so that it can go on to look at the subsequent nodes as well.  Only after it drops out of the while-loop (because floatingNode finally becomes NULL) should it return false.
3. If you were to modify `isAvailable()` slightly so that instead of returning `true` or `false`, it returned either `floatingPointer` or `NULL`, you'd have your mechanism for finding a pointer to the node with the matching data.

e.g.:

```
// Should return either a pointer to the Snode with data==value,
// or NULL if no such Snode is present in the list 
Snode * set::getNodeWithValueOrNullIfNotFound(char value) const
{
   [...]
}

void set::insert(char value)
{
   Snode * theNode = getNodeWithValueOrNullIfNotFound(value);
   if (theNode != NULL)
   {
      theNode->count++;
   }
   else
   {
      [create a new Snode and insert it]
   }
}
```

Comment: An in-order insertion could be useful in limiting the number of iterations required to determine whether the node exists or not. You could iterate on insertion (or within `getNodeWithValueOrNullIfNotFound`) to find where `value` fits in the list and exit the iteration when `node->next->data > value` (checking the next node for `NULL` as required)

Comment: I think we'd better give the questioner a chance to get the basic functionality understood and working, before making the code any more complex.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I just thought it was worth noting. Great answer. I hope this is being done as a learning exercise -- it would be hard to find a less efficient way to track the frequency of characters...

Answer (score 1):

You had a lot of problems in your code, lets see what are they:

1. First of all, `Snode` doesn't need to be a `class`, rather you can go with a simple `strcut`; since we need everything `public`.(not a mistake, but good practice)
2. You could simple initialize `count = 1` and `next = nullptr`, so that no need of initializing them throw constructor. The only element that need to be initialized through constructor is Snod's `data`.
3. Since `c++11` you can use keyword `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, which denotes the [pointer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr).
4. Member function bool `set::isAvailable(char value)` will not work as you think. Here you have unnecessarily created a `new Snode` and cheacking whether it points to `nullptr` which doesn't allow you to even enter the loop. BTW what you have written in the loop also wrong. What do you mean by `return (value == floatingNode);` ? `floatingNode` is a `Snode` by type; not a `char`.

Hear is the correct implementation. Since we don't wanna overwrite the head, will create a `Node*` pointer and assign `head` to it. Then iterate through list until you find a match. If not found, we will reach the end of the `isAvailable()` and return `false`.

> ```
>      inline bool isAvailable(const char& value)
>      {
>          Node *findPos = head;
>
>          while(findPos != nullptr)
>          {
>              if(findPos -> data == value) return true;
>              else findPos = findPos->next_node;
>          }
>          return false;
>      }
> ```

5. In `void set::insert(char value)`,  your logic is correct, but implementation is wrong. Following is the correct implementation.(Hope the comments will help you to understand.

> ```
> void insert(const char& value)
> {
>     if(head == nullptr) // first case
>     {
>         Node *newNode = new Node(value);
>         newNode->next_node = head;
>         head = newNode;
>     }
>     else if(isAvailable(value)) // if node available
>     {
>         Node *temp = head;
>         while(temp->data != value)  // find the node
>             temp = temp->next_node;
>         temp->count += 1;           // and count it by 1
>     }
>     else                            // all new nodes
>     {
>         Node *temp = head;
>         while(temp->next_node != nullptr) // to find the null point (end of list)
>             temp = temp->next_node;
>
>         temp = temp->next_node = new Node(value); // create a node and assign there
>     }
> }
> ```

6. Your destructor will not delete all what you created. It will be UB, since your are deleting newly created `Snode t` ( i.e, `Snode *t = head;`). The correct implementation is as bellow.(un-comment the debugging msg to understand.)

> ```
>    ~set()
>     {
>         Node* temp = head;
>         while( temp != nullptr )
>         {
>             Node* next = temp->next_node;
>             //std::cout << "deleting \t" << temp->data << std::endl;
>             delete temp;
>             temp = next;
>         }
>         head = nullptr;
>     }
> ```

Last but not least, the naming (`set`) what you have here and what the code exactly doing are both different. This looks more like a simple linked list with no duplicates. This is however okay, in order to play around with pointers and list.

To make the code or iteration more efficient, you could do something like follows. In the `isAvailable()`, in case of value match/ if you found a `node`, you could simply increment its count as well. Then in `insert()`, you can think of, if `node` is **not** available part.

Hope this was helpful. See a [DEMO](https://www.ideone.com/85HrRO)

---

```
#include <iostream>

// since you wanna have all of Node in public, declare as struct
struct Node
{
    char data;
    int count = 1;
    Node*  next_node = nullptr;
    Node(const char& a) // create a constrcor which will initilize data
        : data(a) {}    // at the time of Node creation
};

class set
{
private:
    Node *head;             // need only head, if it's a simple list
public:
    set()   :head(nullptr) {}   // constructor set it to nullptr
    ~set()
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        while( temp != nullptr )
        {
            Node* next = temp->next_node;
            //std::cout << "deleting \t" << temp->data << std::endl;
            delete temp;
            temp = next;
        }
        head = nullptr;
    }

    inline bool isAvailable(const char& value)
    {
        Node *findPos = head;

        while(findPos != nullptr)
        {
            if(findPos -> data == value) return true;
            else findPos = findPos->next_node;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void insert(const char& value)
    {
        if(head == nullptr) // first case
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node(value);
            newNode->next_node = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else if(isAvailable(value)) // if node available
        {
            Node *temp = head;
            while(temp->data != value)  // find the node
                temp = temp->next_node;
            temp->count += 1;           // and count it by 1
        }
        else                            // all new nodes
        {
            Node *temp = head;
            while(temp->next_node != nullptr) // to find the null point (end of list)
                temp = temp->next_node;

            temp = temp->next_node = new Node(value);
        }
    }

    void print() const      // just to print
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << temp->data << " " << temp->count << "\n";
            temp = temp->next_node;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    ::set mySet;

    mySet.insert('a');
    mySet.insert('a');
    mySet.insert('b');
    mySet.insert('b');
    mySet.insert('c');
    mySet.insert('a');

    mySet.print();

    return 0;
}
```